# Usage and meaning of "Up next" and “Coming up next"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, phrase-usage

What's the meaning and usage of "up next"and "coming up next”. I often hear this phrase in Television and radio. Are there any other usage of them? What do they mean? I think they mean something is coming after something. I am not sure.

Comment: You may want to compare its use in broadcast with Merriam Webster's definition 4b in its entry for [the phrasal verb "come up"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/come%20up).

Answer (score 5):

Both these phrases "**Up next**" and "**Coming up next**" mean the same thing - *next to come/appear/play/start is; next in queue is*. They are synonyms and indeed most often can be heard in media (especially on channels that broadcast TV Series).

- Up next, the new episode of X-Files.
- Coming up next, The Flash.

Answer (score 4):

They both mean the same thing; "up next" is just a shorter way of saying "coming up next."

You are correct in thinking that something is coming after something. The thing that is "coming up next" is what you should expect to see on television or hear on radio after the current show or segment ends.